# Module exports class Nodes.js

Tags: class, node.js, module

I'm a Nodes.js noob and I'm trying to get my head around module constructs. Thus far I have a module (testMod.js) defined this class construct:

```
var testModule = {
    input : "",
    testFunc : function() {
        return "You said: " + input;
    }
}

exports.test = testModule;
```

I attempt to call the testFunc() method thusly:

```
var test = require("testMod");
test.input = "Hello World";
console.log(test.testFunc);
```

But I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'test'
```

What the frick am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a namespacing issue.  Right now:

```
var test = require("testMod"); // returns module.exports
test.input = "Hello World"; // sets module.exports.input
console.log(test.testFunc); // error, there is no module.exports.testFunc
```

You could do:

```
var test = require("testMod"); // returns module.exports
test.test.input = "Hello World"; // sets module.exports.test.input
console.log(test.test.testFunc); // returns function(){ return etc... }
```

Or, instead of `exports.test` you could do `module.exports = testModule`, then:

```
var test = require("testMod"); // returns module.exports (which is the Object testModule)
test.input = "Hello World"; // sets module.exports.input
console.log(test.testFunc); // returns function(){ return etc... }
```